# Can anti-static spray be used inside the computer, to help all the components from collecting dust?

Tags: desktop, fan, cooling, overheating, case

Can anti static spray be used inside the computer, to help all the components from collecting dust?

If so, I understand the computer would need to be turned off and everything unplugged first.

Is there a specific kind used for computers, that has a diff formula than the kind used on clothes, fabrics, furniture, wood, etc? Or can the same stuff used for clothes be used for outside, around, and inside the computer?

Comment: Old question but if this were a safe path to preventing dust in a PC there would be specialty versions of anti-static spray and tons of tutorials online that would advice and show you how to do this. This is not a good idea and will run a risk of damaging your PC more than dust itself would. Just look at cleaning dust out of a PC the same way someone cleans or vacuums anything: A regular part of basic maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

If you plan on cleaning Dust out of a computer i would use a can of Compressed air or a hoover of some sort, i'd never spray anything else on something electronic like a computer!

Here's a link to some compressed air
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-COMPRESSED-AIR-DUSTER-CLEANER-CAN-Laptop-PC-Keyboard-Camera-Lens-Others-/141854924852?hash=item2107366034:g:fcgAAOSwAvJXDERr

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned the dust out with a vacuum on blow. --- What I'm wanting to know, can the anti-static spray that is labeled for computers be sprayed inside the computer, to prevent dust from collecting? --- Is there anything like that available? --- The rooms of computer banks must use something to prevent the dust from collecting, other than making the room a dust-free environment. ---  I've seen such rooms on diff TV shows & movies. I always wonder how they keep the dust away, every time I see such a scene.